# How can I tell which Docker image(s) are safely to remove?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image

When I run `docker image ls` I see this

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                         <none>              c012c1e2eb45        4 hours ago         2.59GB
<none>                         <none>              a2013debf751        5 hours ago         2.59GB
<none>                         <none>              0bbb2f67083c        5 hours ago         2.59GB
<none>                         <none>              af18b070061b        29 hours ago        182MB
<none>                         <none>              186a8fac122e        35 hours ago        1.67GB
<none>                         <none>              0f90c1bb12a3        35 hours ago        182MB
<none>                         <none>              b94009e70416        13 days ago         631MB
<none>                         <none>              880d8e6713cf        2 weeks ago         631MB
b/2018-external                latest              128d208a6c83        2 weeks ago         207MB
2018-external                  latest              128d208a6c83        2 weeks ago         207MB
b/2018-web                     <none>              128d208a6c83        2 weeks ago         207MB
nginx                          latest              9e7424e5dbae        2 weeks ago         108MB
node                           8-alpine            4db2697ce114        4 weeks ago         67.7MB
b_web                          latest              d5a0ea011c0a        5 weeks ago         182MB
<none>                         <none>              957c22ababec        5 weeks ago         182MB
docker_web                     latest              70b443ed0495        5 weeks ago         182MB
docker_app                     latest              509d58a68224        5 weeks ago         756MB
b_app                          latest              509d58a68224        5 weeks ago         756MB
mysql                          5.6                 96dc914914f5        5 weeks ago         299MB
mysql                          latest              5fac85ee2c68        8 weeks ago         408MB
redis                          latest              1fb7b6c8c0d0        2 months ago        107MB
alpine                         3.6                 76da55c8019d        2 months ago        3.97MB
nginx                          1.13.3-alpine       ba60b24dbad5        5 months ago        15.5MB
keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine   6                   4a09bfc067d6        5 months ago        75.3MB
dockercloud/cli                latest              051238cd0a37        6 months ago        64.2MB
andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm       latest              ec6cc741eb0e        7 months ago        580MB
nginx                          1.10                0346349a1a64        8 months ago        182MB
php                            7.0.8-fpm           75b880f3a420        17 months ago       375MB
tutum/haproxy                  latest              33bc771bec1e        18 months ago       232MB
php                            7.0.4-fpm           81d7a2fdc6dc        21 months ago       494MB
```

How do I know if which image are safely to remove ?

My attention is to remove all of them, but I am not sure if I should be more carful before doing that.

Comment: What do you mean "safely"? Docker won't let you remove an image that is being used by a container.

Comment: Ohh ok. Then, I can go a head and do `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`
 followed by `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: What I mean my `safely` is, I just don't want to remove any images that might require for my other containers that might not be running at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `docker image prune` to remove "dangling" images; those that are not tagged (eg `<none>`) **and** are not referenced by any **running** container.

I find the `docker image prune -a` more useful. It will remove any image that is not used by a running container. In that sense prune -a is a cleanup step that you can take after your environment is running correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Images that are referred to as dangling are safe to remove. Those are the images that don't have a tag. They result when a new build of an image appears and the new image takes the tag leaving the dangling images with `<none>:<none>`
tag.

Dangling images can be listed using  `docker images --filter "dangling=true"` and can be removed by running `docker image prune`.

Comment: The images having name and tag as none in `docker images` are dangled. How to check their size? Also, the images having name and tag as none in `docker images -a` are intermediate images. Can they be deleted and how to check their size?

Answer (score 0):

This command also work for me.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Purging All Unused or Dangling Images, Containers, Volumes, and Networks:**

Clean up any resources — images, containers, volumes, and networks — that are dangling (not associated with a container):

```
docker system prune
```

Remove any stopped containers and all unused images (not just dangling images):

```
docker system prune -a
```

**Remove one or more specific images:**`docker rmi Image  Image`

**Remove dangling images:**`docker images purge`

**Removing images according to a pattern:**`docker images -a | grep "pattern" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi`

**Remove all images:**`docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)`

**Remove one or more specific containers:** `docker rm ID_or_Name  ID_or_Name`
**Remove a container upon exit(run and remove):** `docker run --rm image_name`

**Remove all exited containers:** `docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)`

**Remove containers using more than one filter:** `docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -f status=created -q)`

**Stop and remove all containers:**

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

[Original article on digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)